# Convert Int into time

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a field into the correct format that I would like. 
The field is suppose to keep track of time, but it does it in military time and it is set as an Int.

Can anyone help me in finding a solution for this

I need to do this so I can eventually track the length it took a record to go from one status to another.

```
LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar, [POSTTIME], 100),7))
```

I tried this, but no luck.

here is an example of what the values are and what I would like to change them into:

```
945 = 9:45

1516= 3:16
```

Comment: "15:16" <> "3:16".  Those are very different *times*.

Comment: Correct, I was hoping to change it from a 24-hour clock notation. to a 12-hour clock notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution, As @Gordon Linoff gives the solution you can archive your requirement by using `timefromparts()` function, you also can get the result as per your need as I explained as below.

**Solution 1:** Time With `AM/PM`.

```
DECLARE @IntValue INT  = 1516

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, timefromparts(@IntValue / 100, @IntValue % 100, 0, 0, 0), 100)  AS Time
```

**OutPut**

[image]

**Solution 2:** Time Without `AM/PM`.

```
DECLARE @IntValue INT  = 1516

SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, timefromparts(@IntValue / 100, @IntValue % 100, 0, 0, 0), 100) ,PATINDEX('%[a,p]m',CONVERT(VARCHAR, timefromparts(@IntValue / 100, @IntValue % 100, 0, 0, 0), 100) )-1) AS Time
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about `timefromparts()`?

```
select timefromparts(col / 100, col % 100, 0, 0, 0)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd68d075e3030ee8f66771a5f17a16ac) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  The time value `15:16:00` is not the same as `3:16:00`.  Your question explicitly says to convert into a "time", which I interpret as the native type.  You can convert the value to a 12-hour clock, from the `time` value.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar,TIMEFROMPARTS(1516 / 100, 1516 % 100, 0, 0, 0),100)` will turn Gordon's result (which is data type `TIME`) into a `varchar` representation with your AM/PM swap in place.